# how to filter empty string in azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

How can I filter out an empty string in a field?
I have tried search.ismatch() using "filter" option and regex using "search" option, but none of them worked.

Comment: `$filter=FieldName ne ''` ?

Answer (score 4):

As commented by juunas, `$filter=FieldName ne ''` should do the trick for you if your field is of type Edm.String. In addition if you want to filter out empty collection fields, you can do something like `$filter=FieldName/any()`

Also, to clarify search.ismatch() is a way to include search ranking in filter expressions. The matching criteria takes affect only on documents that satisfy the filter expression. For more details, look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search

Comment: Yea, figured it out. Thank you. Also, in my implementation, fields in a different is set to 'null' for empty values. So, for future implementation, please check the field value. Either set to $filter=[FieldName] ne '' or $filter=[FieldName] ne null.